# Service DMR V8 pedals - V2 and V2.1

Tags: pedals

I have been using DMR V8 pedals on my bikes for just a couple of months. They started to spin slowly and make noise really quick so I'm trying to service them.

I'm not sure that I got it right with the versions. It's a bit confusing on their web site.

These are the two pedals I got. I bought both as just "DMR V8" pedals so it's a bit confusing :)

[image: DMR V8 v2 and v2.1]

[image: DMR V8 v2 and v2.1]

[image: DMR V8 v2 and v2.1]

**DMR V8 V2**

The one with hexnut endcap is v2.
DMR says I cannot get any service parts for V2. Are there any other way to service them? Could I for example use the platforms from V2 with service kits for V2.1?

[image: Screenshot for service parts DMR v8 v2 - sold out]

**DMR V2 V2.1**

I think the one with the grey plastic end cap is v2.1.

It seems as I must buy a special tool to be able to tighten the lock nut. It's too tight to reach with tools I currently have and have been able to service many pedals with in the past.

[image: DMR V8 V2.1 - Service kit]

Ideas or workarounds?

***Update:*** I bought a new pair of shimano platform pedals instead so I'm in no hurry to fix these. But I really don't like to throw away new products that SHOULD work. When / if I get the time I'll just open both up and se if the inner parts are interchangeable.

Comment: I don't really know anything about these either but it may be that all you need is to clean and then re-grease the bearings.  Have you tried removing the hex nut?

Comment: Yes I have. On what I think is V2.1 it looks like its glide bearings but that sounds really strange. On V2 it looks like a normal cup and cone beneath some plastic shields. I'll add screenshots of the details from their website in a second + photos from when I have disassembled the pedals (again).

Comment: ''You can still buy bushes for V2'' should be the main wear parts

Comment: Some pedals are just consumables and not meant for being taken apart and rebuilt. Sad reality. Spares can be more expensive than a new unit. Another sad reality!